# Conditional rendering possible?

Tags: jquery, handlebars.js, mustache

Is it possible to do conditional rendering using Mustache? Example: If I want to display a different value based on the status of X?
eg.

```
if x.value=1
                        <td>                                            
                            <span class="label label-success">{{this.X1}}</span></td>                       
else x.value=2                                                              
                        <td>                                            
                            <span class="label label-warning"{{this.X2}}</span></td>
else if x.value=3                         
                        <td>                                            
                            <span class="label label-inverse"{{this.X3}}</span> </td>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After digging into the documentation, I found that this can be achieved using the Helpers:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('HelperName', function (status) {
            var statusClass = {
                '1': 'label-inverse',
                '2': 'label-important',
                '3': 'label-warning',
                '4': 'label-success'
            };
            return statusClass[status];
        });
```

and using it in the template like:

```
<td>                                            
<span class="label {{HelperName this.myStatus}}">TEXT</span>                                
</td>
```

Answer (score 5):

I believe the only thing you can do is check boolean properties e.g.

```
{{#IsLate}}
    <span class="late">You owe me money, sucka.</span>
{{/IsLate}}
{{^IsLate}}
    <span class="on-time">No money due at this time.</span>
{{/IsLate}}
```

You may want to look into constructing a new wrapper object that suits your needs.

Comment: for opening of a true condition it's `{{#IsLate}}` not `{{IsLate}}`.

Comment: Interesting. So, if the conditional value is not boolean it won't work with Mustache??

Comment: Right the whole point of Mustache is "logic-less templates." I believe you can do this with Handlebars though.